# 'with open()' not working?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, io

I have the code:

```
filename = "C:/users/patrik/documents/mypython.txt"
with open(filename) as f:
    if f.readlines()[0] == "patrik's file": #first line
        f.write("This file has been read by patrik!")
```

Why does it not work? I'm not receiving any errors, and the file content gets messy after this, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: the file content gets really messy, it looks different every time, it has some weird characters which I can't paste here...

Comment: When you say "no error" do you mean `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'`?

Comment: Don't name a variable `file`, it shadows the built-in. Also, you opened the file for reading only, so you cannot write to it. And `file` is a string, `f` is the file, so `file.readlines()` won't work.

Comment: @Eric no, sorry I fixed the `file` and `f` mix, I had it correct in my program :) And Martin okay thanks, I'll rename it!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I hate to disagree, but `file` is a perfectly cromulent variable name.  Especially in Python 3, where it *isn't* a builtin. ;^)

Comment: @DSM: years of Py2 conditioning; if it's gone in 3 the I'm fine with it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform both read and write operations on your file you can choose one of these modes:

`'r+'` :

> Opens a file for both reading and writing. The file pointer will be at
>   the beginning of the file.

`'a+'`:

> Opens a file for both appending and reading. The file pointer is at
>   the end of the file if the file exists. The file opens in the append
>   mode. If the file does not exist, it creates a new file for reading
>   and writing.

Note that `file` is a builtin function in python, so you should not use it as a variable name

Comment: Also ```file``` is a Python builtin, use another variable name.

Comment: Uhhh sorry had `f` in my actual script! Do I have to open it twice them, if I want to read it too?

Comment: He should open the file in `r+` mode instead. Read *and* write. `w` will *clear* the file first.

Comment: @MartijnPieters may be `a+` is a better idea?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Then the file pointer is moved to the end of the file, and on some platforms you *cannot* move it forward from there.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll be using `r+`, it seems to work fine, the problem was in the writing when opening for read! :)

Comment: Eh! why the downvote? @downvoter I can edit my solution if you haven't liked anything about it, please let me know.